CMake unable to find Python3 in Windows with Miniconda installed
I'm trying to build a project using CMake on Windows, but I'm encountering an error where CMake can't find Python3. I have Miniconda installed on my system.
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find Python3 (missing: Python3_EXECUTABLE Interpreter)

I have added the following paths to environment variable Path:
C:\Users\Jiawei\miniconda3
C:\Users\Jiawei\miniconda3\Library\bin
C:\Users\Jiawei\miniconda3\Scripts

Additionally, if I tape python in Command Prompt, a pop-up window will show and guide me to install python from Microsoft Store.
